# Use stereo DAC for mono application

Tags: audio, dac, sound, stereo

I am developing an audio device that will have a mono audio output. I currently use the PCM5102A stereo DAC in my prototype as it is easy to find as a separate module. But it does have a stereo output, which means I have one extra, unused channel. What is the best way to solve this problem?

1. Use only one channel from a stereo DAC
2. Combine two channels into one. How?
3. Switch to a different DAC.

Comment: What is your input signal feeding the DAC?

Comment: What's the matter with using just one channel?

Comment: @td127 I'm building wavetable synth in eurorack format, input is I2S coded periodic waves.

Comment: @TimWescott I do not know - this is the question:) Maybe the use of two channels can achieve some better accuracy or S/N value?

Comment: 1 may be simplest and it's fine.

Comment: Wavetable synth, cool. You only need one channel, so you can just use one half of your stereo DAC. One trick you can do is hook up both channels, send the exact same data to both sides, and sum the two analog outputs into mono. This summing can simply be putting a ~1K resistor on each output and tying them together. What you gain is an extra 3dB of signal to noise ratio (because your signal is doubled, +6dB, but the two uncorrelated noise components only add +3dB). The cost of doing this is paying for the extra analog output channel.

Comment: _"input is I2S coded periodic waves"_- I2S is a stereo data format, so what are you sending on the other channel? How are you creating the I2S signal?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, it is stereo, but data is coded for each channel separately. The first part of 16-bit is for left channel, the second part is for right. To fill the second channel with empty values I just made uin32_t DMA buffer(instead of uint16_t). The first part of uint32_t is filled with actual data, the second part is unused and left as is.

Comment: @td127 Thank you for the idea! I think I can feed both outputs to summing op amp and at the same time change amplitude range, suitable to eurorack format.